# Box Selection depth config

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How can I make the same selection with a box as in Revit?
From left to right - selection without penetration depth and from right to left with penetration depth.

Comment: Could you illustrate what the `penetration depth` is? The BoxSelection supports drawing box from right to left with my test.

Comment: @EasonKang
Hello, Eason Kang! I was able to achieve the selection of the frame with Box Selection as in Revit using the parameter 'useGeometricIntersection' (viewer.load Extension('Autodesk.BoxSelection', { useGeometricIntersection: true })). But there is still a problem of sampling elements deep. For example, I want to select a wall with a selection box. This wall is selected, but at the same time everything that is behind it selected too. I spoke about this penetration into the depth. I want to select only those elements that are visible on the client's screen.